# Oracle multple rows to single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-aggregation

I want to concatenate multiple rows to a sigle row in oracle. Below is what I am trying to achieve

case table

```
case_id Name
1       AAA
2       BBB
```

Subject table

```
case_id Subject
1       ENG
1       MATH
1       SCI
2       ENG
2       HIS
```

SUB_LOOKUP table

```
Abbr    Subject
ENG     English
MATH    Mathematics
SCI     Science
HIS     History
```

Expected Output

```
1   AAA     English, Mathematics, Science
2   BBB     English, History
```

I tried using LISTAGG function as below. It lists what I would want to achieve  but the issue comes when I join with the lookup table and then join to main table.

```
SELECT c.case_id, c.category_id, LISTAGG(cs.special_interest_cd) WITHIN GROUP 
(ORDER BY cs.special_interest_cd) AS description
FROM CASE_SPECIAL_INTEREST cs, cases c
where c.case_id = cs.case_id
GROUP BY c.case_id;
```

Tried joining 2 tables but getting "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"
Can someone help with joining the 3 tables. Is it possible to achieve the same without LISTAGG since i read it throws eception when the max character is reached for varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a basic join between the three tables, followed by an aggregation by `case_id` and `name`:

```
SELECT
    c.case_id,
    c.Name,
    LISTAGG(sl.subject, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sl.subject) AS subject
FROM "case" c
LEFT JOIN subject s
    ON c.case_id = s.case_id
LEFT JOIN sub_lookup sl
    ON s.Subject = sl.Abbr
GROUP BY
    c.case_id,
    c.Name;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Note that I use left joins here, to ensure that if a given `case_id` has no matches for the aggregation, that record/value would still be reported in the result set.

Comment: thank you. When I run this query independently it works great and gives me result exactly like what i want. But I have to add this query inside an already exisiting query which is really huge and the result is 1   AAA  Mathematics. I cant paste the original query  here since its like 500 lines of code but any suggestions?

Comment: No, I can't make a suggestion without seeing the actual query.